# Firebase user is undefined right after I sign in the user in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a login form that will log in the user (at least thats what i want it to do), when I try to get any user info from the firebase object, it doesn't work or it works weird. I have almost two identical functions bellow.

Submit form version 1 (Does not print out the user uid, error instead)

```
function lsubmitForm() {
// initiate variables with form content

var email = document.getElementById('lemail').value;
var password = document.getElementById('lpassword').value;

//login in the user
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

console.log(user.uid)
```

}

lsubmitform v2 (will print out user.uid)

```
function lsubmitForm() {
// initiate variables with form content

var email = document.getElementById('lemail').value;
var password = document.getElementById('lpassword').value;

//login in the user
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        console.log(user.uid)
    } else {

    }
  });

}
```

Why is this so? Why does the latter snippet log the user.uid? Is it some type of scope issue? Why is the first snippet not able to grab the current user? Is it an asynchronous call? do I need to force it to wait to print out the uid after it signs in the user? I'm not sure how to fix this, javascript is not my forte.

the function is called when a form is submitted.

Comment: _Is it an asynchronous call?_ - yes it is.

Comment: The `.signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method returns a Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first snippet, you are not awaiting the promise of registering the user to finish. You should declare your functions async and then add an await. This way it will wait for the process to finish and then continue

```js
function lsubmitForm() async {
// initiate variables with form content

var email = document.getElementById('lemail').value;
var password = document.getElementById('lpassword').value;

//login in the user
await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

console.log(user.uid)
```

The changes are on the first line, added async, and on the registering user which has an await at the start. I would recommend looking at the google documentation on async/await, there are some really good videos.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are wondering why the first snippet doesn't log anything. Right? (sorry, I could ask this on a comment, but I can't write comments before I get 50 of reputation).

If the question is this, I think that the first snippet registers the new user, but you don' t see any message in the console because the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function is asynchronous and the `console.log` will be called before that the signInWithEmailAndPassword has finished. So when the console.log is called the user will not exist yet.

In the second snippet instead, you are printing the uid only when there's an auth state change (the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` changes the auth state), and that means that if the auth state change is provoked by the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function the user will always exist, and therefore the uid will exist too, so you can console.log it.

I hope this helped you!